# Post selected option's value to second page using sessions

Tags: php, html, forms, session, post

I've been trying to post the value of two selected dropdown menu's using the SESSIONS method, however there seems to be an issue because when submitted the second page displays the PHP code only. Here are the relevant snippets of code:

### shop.php

```
<form action="processing.php" method="post"> <div class="item">
    <span class="caption">Essential Gray Suit<br />£459</span>
    <select name="size1" class="size" id="size1" onchange="showDiv(this)">
        <optgroup label="Size">
        <option value="0">SELECT SIZE</option>
        <option value="1">XS</option>
        <option value="2">S</option>
        <option value="3">M</option>
        <option value="4">L</option>
        <option value="5">XL</option>
    </select>

    <div id="quantity1" style="display: none;">
    <select name="quantity1" class="size"  onchange="showCart(this)">
        <optgroup label="Quantity">
        <option value="0">SELECT QUANTITY</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

### processing.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['size1'] = $_POST['size1'];
} 


echo $_SESSION['size1'];

?>
```

Comment: If PHP code is showing up in your web browser, then that means the server hosting your code is not configured to run PHP.

Comment: anyways, u used `session_start()` two times with what sort of reason?

Comment: you have used two times `session_start()`. why did you do this. Top of the `session_start()` is enough.

Comment: Problem has been solved, i forgot to run XAMPP. My apologies everyone! @crush thank you for saving me further embarrassment